# Selenium table data processing

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to process data from table by grabbing either the full table and working with it as an object or the individual rows.

I can grab the  from within a row and work with it as so

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='cl_details_container']/a")

time.sleep(5)

for e in elements:
    print(e.get_attribute('title'))
    print(e.get_attribute('href'))
    print(e.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

But what i would like to do is maybe grab an upper-level block such as

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='cl_details']")
```

And work with that as it holds all the info, I need but I'm not getting anywhere with it, i just empty or object ids printed out. Other than that, I'm going to have to do

```
elements = driver.find_elements ..........
```

For every piece of data I need, any clues please :)

Ideally grabbing the complete table in one call would be less likely to upset the website

FYI this is not to web scrape or anything like that, I'm trying to automate my job slightly and don't want the company whose web site it is getting annoyed as in reality it should cut down on human traffic and use if it goes to plan.

I tried various combinations of parent child access, but the table object returns empty

Edit:

Using the following XPath

```
table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/table")
```

I get the following when i call print(table)

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="7a3a792477910d55630d102e9ed41a5a", element="2e620502-f1ae-46a7-bb8b-901ab38142bd")>
```

Comment: Can you share the link to the site or at least the html you are trying to work with?

Comment: It's a bit difficult without sharing the user data also, I can grab the table or items within using xpath I'm just wondering how to get the whole table then work with it within python if that's even possible